# Vue.js - Component template not rendering with v-for

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have method that calls ajax to my api and that response which returns I assigning it to an array. After that in template section with `v-for` I display data. It render only one time after I change something in data to display. After refresh it is not displaying anymore.

No errors in console, and vue shows that array is filled with returned response.

Template:

```
<template>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <h5 class="component-title">Game board</h5>
      <button v-for="number in board" v-bind:key="number.results" :class="'col-1 btn btn-'+number.colors">{{number.positionToId}}</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Script section:

```
import RouletteApi from "@/services/api/Roulette";
export default {
  name: "GameBoard",
  data() {
    return {
      board: []
    };
  },
  created() {
    this.getBoardLayout();
  },
  methods: {
    getBoardLayout() {
      RouletteApi.getLayout().then(response => {
        //this.rLayout.orgResponse = response;
        for (var i = 0; i < response.slots; i++) {
          this.board[i] = {
            results: response.results[i],
            positionToId: response.positionToId[i],
            colors: response.colors[i]
          };
        }
      });
    }
  }
};
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have no reactivity by using that method to fill your array so try this using `push` function:

```
methods: {
  getBoardLayout() {
    RouletteApi.getLayout().then(response => {
      //this.rLayout.orgResponse = response;
      for (var i = 0; i < response.slots; i++) {
        this.board.push({
          results: response.results[i],
          positionToId: response.positionToId[i],
          colors: response.colors[i]
        });
      }
    });
  }
}
```

or using `this.$set`  instance method :

```
 methods: {
    getBoardLayout() {
      RouletteApi.getLayout().then(response => {
        //this.rLayout.orgResponse = response;
        for (var i = 0; i < response.slots; i++) {
          this.$set(this.board,i, {
            results: response.results[i],
            positionToId: response.positionToId[i],
            colors: response.colors[i]
          });
        }
      });
    }
  }
```