# VueJS linear-guage not rendering

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a loop, and if I view source I can see the value is passed correctly. However, the template uses:

```
"vue-canvas-gauges": "0.0.0",
"canvas-gauges": "^2.1.5",
```

If I open the console and edit anything, it re-renders and shows the value.

here is the relevant part of the template:

```
<div class="col-xs-3 col-xs-offset-1" v-for="item in buildings">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">{{item.name}}</div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <canvas data-width="100" :data-value="item.completion_status" data-type="linear-gauge"></canvas>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have the following method, called on mounted:

```
methods: {
  async fetchData() {
    axios.get('/api/v1/buildings').then(response => {
      this.buildings=response.data.data;
    });
  }
}
```

so, on mounted I call this.fetchData, and the generated HTML on the page is correct

```
<div class="col-xs-3 col-xs-offset-1">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">Bldg1</div> 
        <div class="panel-body">
            <canvas data-width="100" width="100" data-value="0" data-type="linear-gauge"></canvas>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried using push idea from the following answer:
[Vue.js - Component template not rendering with v-for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53253125/vue-js-component-template-not-rendering-with-v-for)

Comment: I have not tried also making it computed property.

I tried a few other things from every search I can do,  but after enough back and forth I am lost.

Manually editing canvas makes it appear, which I read is related to how vue handles the component and how the console works with vue. I keep trying, any ideas would help

Comment: When I tried to put the loop directly into component it works.

    <canvas v-for="(content, index) in cars" data-width="100" :data-value="content.value" data-type="linear-gauge"></canvas>